# load a new google map in current page with load ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I try to load a java script google map v3 in my index page with ajax load:

I know it there a lot of same question but I couldn't underestand them.

**index.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
          html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          #map { height: 100%; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="mapc"></div>

      <span id="btn">load map</span>

        <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#mapc").load("map.php");
        initMap();
        });
     });
        </script>
        <script async defer
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Note: I need google API link be in index.php because I plan to have anoher google map in index.php too.

also this is **map.php**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Also in console I only get this error:

```
js?callback=initMap:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null_.Af @ js?callback=initMap:74_.hg @ js?callback=initMap:81initMap @ (index):19(anonymous function) @ js?callback=initMap:87(anonymous function) @ js?callback=initMap:49_.ac @ js?callback=initMap:46oc @ js?callback=initMap:49(anonymous function) @ js?callback=initMap:123google.maps.Load @ js?callback=initMap:21(anonymous function) @ js?callback=initMap:122(anonymous function) @ js?callback=initMap:123
js?callback=initMap:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null_.Af @ js?callback=initMap:74_.hg @ js?callback=initMap:81initMap @ (index):19(anonymous function) @ (index):28n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the `initMap();` just **after** that the **map.php** was loaded.

So, you need to call the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) function with **2** parameters:

1. URL.
2. Callback function.

**jQuery docs**

> **Callback Function**
>
> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

In the callback function you can be sure that the **map.php** was loaded and the `#map` div exist in the DOM.

```
$("#mapc").load("map.php", function() {
   initMap();
});
```

**Also, remove the `?callback=initMap` from the URL**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Element () not exists on page load.
You add the  first after clicked the "#btn".

It works first after clicking, see:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#mapc").append('<div id="map"></div>');
        initMap();
        });
     });
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          #map { height: 100%;     width: 500px;
    height: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var map;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
</script>

      <div id="mapc"></div>

      <button id="btn">load map</button>

        <script async defer
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
        </script>
```

Just remove the "?callback=initMap" Parameter and it works fine, without errors.